# How to mark methods to be invoked only from the main thread in Obj-C?

Tags: xcode9-beta, compiler-options, xcode9

I'm experimenting with the new Xcode 9 [Main Thread Checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker?language=objc)

This is pretty neat. I'd like to now mark / annotate my Obj-C methods to be invoked only from the main thread so the Main Thread Checker can kick-in automatically when attached to the debugger. I can't find any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (see update). But you could use an assert to do it manually (like PSPDFKit does for [example](https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345#file-pspdfuikitmainthreadguard-m-L58))

```
assert(Thread.isMainThread, "Method must be called from the MainThread only!")
```

## Update:

There's no way. [Tweet from an employee](https://twitter.com/zaks_anna/status/873680917436350464):

> unfortunately not; you cannot teach Main Thread Checker about you APIs (CC @kubamracek)
>
> > by @zaks_anna (Program analysis @apple)

Update2: There's an open radar being tracked by Apple, with ID#32659599. So hopefully, it will be implemented soon™.

Comment: I'm already doing this - I'd like to trip the Main Thread Checker somehow. There has to be a way since the documentation clearly states the following:

Unlike other code diagnostic tools, the Main Thread Checker doesn't require recompilation, and can be used with existing binaries.

Comment: Sadly you can't (for now): updated response with tweet from an Apple employee

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with Main Thread Checker is that it can catch execution main-thread only code on a background thread when that reaches it i.e. on runtime.

The real solution would be to use static checking even before code is executed since sometimes is really hard to go trough all use cases in a non-trivial application.

More over, it is not quite an info (assert) that code is executing on a wrong thread while it will crash a moment later anyway.

I would like to see something like this in Swift:
`@mainThreadOnly` and `@isOnMainThread`

and

`if #mainThreadOnly && !#isOnMainThread { raise_warning }`